# How many natural numbers $n$ not greater than $10000$ are there such that $2^n - n^2$ is divisible by $7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

How many natural numbers $n$ not greater than $10000$ are there such that $2^n - n^2$ is divisible by $7$?

Please help me solve this question!

Comment: What have you tried?  For instance, have you made a table of powers of 2 modulo 7?  Do you know which residues modulo 7 are squares?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm aware of that property! I did try it but I'm stuck now

Comment: Computed the solutions : $2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 15, 23, 25, 26, 27, 31$

Comment: @Wyllich $n=36,44,46,47,48,\dots$ are a solutions as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RobertZ You are right. Might be related to constant conversion issues.

Comment: @Wyllich Taking modulo $7$, the term $2^n$ repeats for every three numbers because $2^3$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $7$. The other term $n^2$ repeats for every seven numbers, of course, when taken modulo $7$. The least common multiple is $3\cdot 7=21$. Therefore, if you inspect the computed solution, the pattern repeats in every "block" of length $21$. So you can count all solutions between $1$ and $21$ by brute force. Then repeat this block all over. You need to be careful in the end because the last block will not be full (10000 is not divisible by 21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Since $2^3\equiv 1 \pmod {7}$, consider $n=3q+r$ with the remainder $r=0,1,2$.

If $r=0$, then $1\leq q \leq 3333$ and 
$$0\equiv 2^n - n^2=1-9q^2\equiv 1-2q^2\implies q\equiv 2, q\equiv 5\pmod{7}$$
Therefore the number of $n=6q$ is equal to
$$\left\lfloor\frac{3333-2}{7}\right\rfloor+1+\left\lfloor\frac{3333-5}{7}\right\rfloor+1=952.$$

Now consider the remaining similar cases. At the end you should find that for $r=1,2$ the number of $n$s are respectively $953$, $953$.

Therefore the answer should be $952+953+953=2858$.

Comment: can you explain me the case work once in detail?

Comment: why is the limit of q till 1666? On multiplying we get 9996 which is 4 less than the question! why cant $r$ also take value 4 or 5?

Comment: @LinuxGeek $q\leq 1666$ is the limit when $r=0$ (it is the number of positive multiple of $6$ which are less or equal to $10000$. It changes for other values of $r$.

Comment: Already for exponent $3$ we get $2^3\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen Many thanks. Now the solution is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

We need $$2^n\equiv n^2\pmod7$$

Now for integer $n, n^2\equiv0,1\equiv8,2,4\pmod7$

For $n^2\equiv0\pmod7,$ we need $$2^n\equiv0\pmod7$$ which is untenable (why?)

For $n^2\equiv1\pmod7\iff n\equiv\pm1\ \ \ \  (1),$

we need $$2^n\equiv1\pmod7\iff n\equiv0\pmod3\ \ \ \  (2)$$

By $(1),(2): n\equiv6,15\pmod{21}$

For $n^2\equiv2\pmod7\iff n\equiv\pm3\ \ \ \  (3),$

we need $$2^n\equiv2\pmod7\iff n\equiv1\pmod3\ \ \ \  (4)$$

By $(3),(4): n\equiv10,4\pmod{21}$

For $n^2\equiv4\pmod7\iff n\equiv\pm2\ \ \ \  (5),$

we need $$2^n\equiv4\pmod7\iff n\equiv2\pmod3\ \ \ \  (6)$$

By $(5),(6): n\equiv2,5\pmod{21}$

So, the required number will be $$\sum_{r=\{6,1510,4,2,5\}}\left\lfloor\dfrac{10000-r}{21}\right\rfloor$$